# OpenCL Host ran out of Memory in trivial Kernel

Tags: c, opencl, opencl-c

I am trying to do the kernel from in a sample learning program with 1024 entries of input buffer and output buffer both arrays of floating point entries of 32bits.
https://anteru.net/blog/2012/getting-started-with-opencl-part-2/

What happens is that my code gives me a CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY when trying to compile the kernel

And this is my `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 210
#include "CL/cl.h"

char* program_src = "__kernel void SAXPY (__global float* x, __global float* y, float a)\n"
"{\n"
"const int i = get_global_id (0);\n"
"y [i] += a * x [i];\n"
"}\n";

int main() {
    cl_platform_id platform_ids[16];
    cl_uint platform_count;

    if (clGetPlatformIDs(16, &platform_ids, &platform_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl platform(s) found\n", platform_count);

    if (platform_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("choosing platform 0...\n");

    cl_device_id device_ids[16];
    cl_int device_count;
    if (clGetDeviceIDs(platform_ids[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 16, &device_ids, &device_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl device(s) found on platform 0\n", device_count);

    if (device_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cl_device_id device = device_ids[0];

    printf("** running test **\n");

    cl_int cl_fehler;
    cl_context ctx = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCommandQueue\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, device, 0, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Replace 1 mit Zahlen von Gärate IDs
    printf("Am clCreateProgram\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, &program_src, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateKernel\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "saxpy", &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    // No point in share the rest of the code because the problem is being hapenning here
}
```

Comment: The error code isn't what I'd expect (I'd have thought `CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME`), but I notice your kernel function is called `SAXPY`, but you're passing `"saxpy"` to `clCreateKernel()`. That certainly won't work. Let us know if fixing that changes anything.

Comment: @pmdj Still is -6

Comment: Looking more closely, I notice you're not calling `clBuildProgram`. I don't think this is optional, unless the specific OpenCL implementation you're using explicitly documents it as being so.

Comment: @pmdj Your comment solved the problem, make it an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 issues with the posted code:

- There is no call to `clBuildProgram` between `clCreateProgramWithSource` and `clCreateKernel`.
- The kernel function is called `SAXPY`, but the `clCreateKernel` call is looking for `"saxpy"`. Names are case-sensitive.

Comment: Are you interested in help with another problem? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/77958881/16031219)