# OpenCL hangs forever when trying to read kernel output

Tags: opencl, opencl-c

This is a follow up to [OpenCL Host ran out of Memory in trivial Kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77843124/16031219) results that after applying the corrections and taking another errors I got that my program hangs at the `EnqueueReadBuffer` for an unknown reason!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 210
#include "CL/cl.h"

char* program_src = "__kernel void SAXPY (__global float* x, __global float* y, float a)\n"
"{\n"
"const int i = get_global_id (0);\n"
"y [i] += a * x [i];\n"
"}\n";

int main() {
    cl_platform_id platform_ids[16];
    cl_uint platform_count;

    if (clGetPlatformIDs(16, &platform_ids, &platform_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl platform(s) found\n", platform_count);

    if (platform_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("choosing platform 0...\n");

    cl_device_id device_ids[16];
    cl_int device_count;
    if (clGetDeviceIDs(platform_ids[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 16, &device_ids, &device_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl device(s) found on platform 0\n", device_count);

    if (device_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cl_device_id device = device_ids[0];

    printf("** running test **\n");

    cl_int cl_fehler;
    cl_context ctx = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCommandQueue\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, device, 0, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Replace 1 mit Zahlen von Gärate IDs
    printf("Am clCreateProgram\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, &program_src, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clBuildProgram\n");
    cl_fehler = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateKernel\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "SAXPY", &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_mem eingabe_buffer = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    printf("Am clCreateBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_mem ausgabe_buffer = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cl_float eingabe_data[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    printf("Am clEnqueueWriteBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, eingabe_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, &eingabe_data, 0, NULL, NULL); 
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &eingabe_buffer);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &ausgabe_buffer);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_float f = 2.0;
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_float), &f);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clEnqueueNDRangeKernel\n");
    const size_t globalWorkSize[3] = { 10, 0, 0 };
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clEnqueueReadBuffer\n");
    cl_float ausgabe_data[3];
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, ausgabe_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, &ausgabe_data, 0, NULL, NULL); 
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // No point in share the rest of the code because the problem is being happening here
}
```

## Update

Afer applying the suggestions from @pmdj the problems persists and can confirm that the clEnqueueReadBuffer part of the loggin is being printed.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 210
#include "CL/cl.h"

char* program_src = "__kernel void SAXPY (__global float* x, __global float* y, float a)\n"
"{\n"
"const int i = get_global_id (0);\n"
"y [i] = a * x [i];\n"
"}\n";

int main() {
    cl_platform_id platform_ids[16];
    cl_uint platform_count;

    if (clGetPlatformIDs(16, &platform_ids, &platform_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl platform(s) found\n", platform_count);

    if (platform_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("choosing platform 0...\n");

    cl_device_id device_ids[16];
    cl_int device_count;
    if (clGetDeviceIDs(platform_ids[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 16, &device_ids, &device_count) != CL_SUCCESS) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%i cl device(s) found on platform 0\n", device_count);

    if (device_count == 0) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cl_device_id device = device_ids[0];

    printf("** running test **\n");

    cl_int cl_fehler;
    cl_context ctx = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCommandQueue\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(ctx, device, 0, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Replace 1 mit Zahlen von Gärate IDs
    printf("Am clCreateProgram\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1, &program_src, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clBuildProgram\n");
    cl_fehler = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateKernel\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "SAXPY", &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_mem eingabe_buffer = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clCreateBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = CL_SUCCESS;
    cl_mem ausgabe_buffer = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, NULL, &cl_fehler);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cl_float eingabe_data[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    printf("Am clEnqueueWriteBuffer\n");
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, eingabe_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, &eingabe_data, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &eingabe_buffer);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), &ausgabe_buffer);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clSetKernelArg\n");
    cl_float f = 2.0;
    cl_fehler = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_float), &f);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Am clEnqueueNDRangeKernel\n");
    const size_t globalWorkSize[3] = { 10, 0, 0 };
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    clFinish(queue);

    printf("Am clEnqueueReadBuffer\n");
    cl_float ausgabe_data[10] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,1 ,1 };
    cl_fehler = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, ausgabe_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, &ausgabe_data[0], 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (cl_fehler != CL_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Fehler: %i\n", cl_fehler);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // No point in share the rest of the code because the problem is being happening here
}
```

## System data update:

The host is openSUSE Leap 15.5 x86_64 on an AMD ATI 04:00.0 Lucienne and AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 1.800GHz with AMD rocm drivers installed systemwide.

I am compiling with `cc src/main.c -lOpenCL -I/opt/rocm-6.0.0/include/ -L/opt/rocm-6.0.0/lib/ -o test`

And I have the `rocm-opencl-sdk` package installed from [here](https://rocm.docs.amd.com/projects/install-on-linux/en/latest/how-to/native-install/sles.html) which is the vendors (AMD's) official page.

Comment: Before reading back the result, and after enqueueing the kernel, try calling `clFinish()` on your queue. Does it now hang in the clFinish call (problem with the kernel) or in the buffer read?

Comment: @pmdj In the buffer read

Answer (score 1):

I can spot at least 3 issues:

#### 1. Buffer size

> ```
> cl_float ausgabe_data[3];
> ---------------------^^^
> ```

versus

> ```
> clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, ausgabe_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_float) * 10, &ausgabe_data, 0, NULL, NULL);
> -------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

This is trying to read 10 floats into a buffer that can hold 3.

#### 2. Pointer syntax

This *may* not cause issues depending on your C compiler, but as far as I'm aware it's not strictly correct. When passing the pointer to the copy destination, you have:

> `…, &ausgabe_data, …`

This takes the address of the array itself, not of the data items within it. In *most* cases these should be the same, but better stick to the safe approach. Either remove the ampersand (`&`) to use the fact that an array automatically degrades into a pointer to its 0th element, or explicitly specify the array item at which to start writing (`&ausgabe_data[0]`).

##### 2a. Ignoring build warnings.

Note that the call to `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` with `&eingabe_data` has the same issue. The `clGetPlatformIDs(16, &platform_ids,` and `clGetDeviceIDs(…, &device_ids,` calls have the same problem, and your compiler should be warning you about these latter 2. (`clEnqueueWriteBuffer` and `clEnqueueReadBuffer` unfortunately are not type safe and accept `void*` so your compiler cannot spot mistakes there. All the more reason to double check them manually.)

Don't ignore warnings! *Please go and fix any other warnings your compiler is telling you about before posting questions here.* If you're not seeing warnings about this, add something like `-Wall -Wextra` to your C compiler flags. Then go fix those issues as well as the ones I identified.

#### 3. Buffer use.

The kernel code uses:

> ```
> y [i] += …
> ```

so, it *reads from y, adds that value to another, then writes it back*. Yet, the buffer for `y` is created as write-only, and its contents is never initialised:

> ```
> cl_mem ausgabe_buffer = clCreateBuffer(ctx, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
> ---------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Either make the buffer read-write and initialise it with sensible initial data (all zeroes?), or change the kernel code to pure assignment. (`y [i] = …`)

Comment: Unfortunately this was not enough to solve the problem.

Comment: @Delfin I've taken another look. I found another instance of issue 2, and an entirely separate major issue, and updated my answer accordingly. (Plus a comment on the question suggesting a debug technique to help identify the source of any remaining issues.)

Comment: Even thought the problem persists in was solved once and when trying to pass to the actual project it did remain, at the same time when trying to apply the fixes again to the MRE it came back again.

Comment: @Delfin As I can't spot any obvious issues other than the remaining pointer type mismatches, I've now tried your updated code, and after fixing all the numerous compiler warnings, it's running without issue on my system. (macOS 14, OpenCL device: M3 Pro) What OpenCL platform are you on, and what exactly is the nature of the hang? Can you take a call stack snapshot?

Comment: Details in another update

Comment: There is not help?

Comment: @Delfin I have no experience with Docker or Vagrant and don't know how they might interact with OpenCL. I would recommend running the minimal sample you have provided on the native OS without any containerisation and checking if you're still seeing the same behaviour. You say it hangs. How does that manifest, exactly? Did you try taking a stack snapshot or connecting a debugger?

Comment: It does fact have the same behaviour, as expected by followings AMD's instructions for using the rocm drivers in containerized environments.

Comment: there will no be help?